# First passage probability formula

Tags: black-scholes, probability, barrier

I recently read an article and they provide a formula for the first-passage probability as

$$Z = {1 \over \sigma }\left[ {\log S/{S_t} + (r - {1 \over 2}{\sigma ^2})t} \right]$$

${{S_t}}$ value of the stock at time t , $r$ ror on the stock, $\sigma $ standard deviation.

The authors ref. Feller (1971) "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Vol 2. " But i have been unable to find the formula , does anyone know where this comes from and any literature where this formula is presented?

Update: Is it derived from this ? $$Z(t) = \exp \left\{ {\sigma X(t) - (\sigma \mu  + {1 \over 2}{\sigma ^2})t} \right\}$$

where $$X(t) = \log S/Sc$$

update: is there a typo in their formula? after reading some literature should it not be the case that the first passage probability should be

$$Z = {1 \over \sigma \sqrt{t} }\left[ {\log S/{S_t} + (r - {1 \over 2}{\sigma ^2})t} \right]$$

Link : [Feller pdf](http://ruangbacafmipa.staff.ub.ac.id/files/2012/02/An-Introduction-to-probability-Theory-by-William-Feller.pdf)

Link Article : https://forum.wilmott.com/download/file.php?id=7750

Comment: What is the article? can you provide a link?

Comment: These existing questions should help: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8846/brownian-motion-first-passage-time; https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/235/probability-of-touching?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How do you define "first passage"? Do you mean "first passage time"?

Answer (score 3):

Their formula looks correct. As is usually the case, there are multi ways to derive this result. I will outline two of them here.

**Reflection Principle & Measure Change**

The solution to the risk-neutral dynamics of $S$ is

\begin{equation}
S_t = S_0 \exp \left\{ \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) t + \sigma W_t^* \right\},
\end{equation}

where $W^*$ is a $\mathbb{P}^*$-Brownian motion. We have $S_t = B$ when

\begin{equation}
W_t^* + \frac{1}{\sigma} \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) t = \frac{1}{\sigma} \ln \left( \frac{B}{S_0} \right).
\end{equation}

Now let

\begin{equation}
\lambda = \frac{1}{\sigma} \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right), \qquad \alpha = \frac{1}{\sigma} \ln \left( \frac{B}{S_0} \right)
\end{equation}

and define a new probability measure $\hat{\mathbb{P}}$ equivalent to $\mathbb{P}^*$ through the Radon-Nikodym derivative process

\begin{equation}
\xi_t \left( \mathbb{P}^*, \hat{\mathbb{P}} \right) = \left. \frac{\mathrm{d} \hat{\mathbb{P}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}^*} \right| \mathfrak{F}_t = \mathcal{E}_t \left( - \int_0^\cdot \lambda \mathrm{d}W_u^* \right) \qquad \mathbb{P}^*\text{-a.s.},
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{E}$ is the Doleans-Dade exponential martingale. It follows by Girsanov's theorem that the process $\hat{W}$ defined by

\begin{equation}
\hat{W}_t = W_t^* + \lambda t
\end{equation}

is a standard Brownian motion under $\hat{\mathbb{P}}$. Next, by the reflection principle for Brownian motion, PDF of the first passage time $\nu$ of $\hat{W}$ to a level $\alpha$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbb{P}} \left\{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}t \right\} = \frac{\vert \alpha \vert}{t \sqrt{2 \pi t}} \exp \left\{ -\frac{\alpha^2}{2 t} \right\} \mathrm{d}t;
\end{equation}

see for example Equation (II.6.3) in Karatzas and Shreve (1991), p. 80 or Theorem 3.7.1. in Shreve (2004), p. 113. I take this result as given and you can find details on its derivation in the references. Using the abstract Bayes rule; see for example Lemma A.1.4 in Musiela and Rutkowski (2005), p. 615, we get

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}^* \left\{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}t \right\} & = & \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}^*} \left[ \mathrm{1} \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}t \} \right]\\
& = & \mathbb{E}_{\hat{\mathbb{P}}} \left[ \xi_t^{-1} \left( \mathbb{P}^*, \hat{\mathbb{P}} \right) \mathrm{1} \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}t \} \right]\\
& = & \mathbb{E}_{\hat{\mathbb{P}}} \left[ \exp \left\{ \lambda \hat{W}_t - \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 t \right\} \mathrm{1} \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}t \} \right].
\end{eqnarray}

Now, when $\nu = t$ then $\hat{W}_t = \alpha$ and thus

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}^* \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}t \} & = & \exp \left\{ \lambda \alpha - \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 t \right\} \hat{\mathbb{P}} \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}t \}\\
& = & \frac{\vert \alpha \vert}{t \sqrt{2 \pi t}} \exp \left\{ -\frac{(\alpha - \lambda t)^2}{2 t} \right\} \mathrm{d}t.
\end{eqnarray}

Note that the $\alpha - \lambda t$ term is equal to $Z$ in your reference.

**Differentiating the Barrier Option Price**

Let $\psi = -1$ ($\psi = +1$) indicate an upper (lower) barrier. Consider a contract with the terminal payoff $V_T = \mathrm{1} \{ \nu > T \}$. Using the method of images, it can be shown that its valuation function in terms of the time-to-maturity $\tau = T - t$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\tilde{V}(S, \tau) = \mathcal{B}_B^\psi(S, \tau) - \mathcal{I} \left\{ \mathcal{B}_B^\psi(S, \tau) \right\},
\end{equation}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{B}_B^\psi & = & e^{-r \tau} \mathcal{N} \left( \psi d_-(S, B) \right),\\
d_-(S, B) & = & \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{\tau}} \left( \ln \left( \frac{S}{B} \right) + \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \tau \right),\\
\mathcal{I} \left\{ \tilde{V}(S, \tau) \right\} & = & \left( \frac{S}{B} \right)^{2 \alpha} \tilde{V} \left( \frac{B^2}{S}, \tau \right)\\
\alpha & = & \frac{1}{2} - \frac{r}{\sigma^2};\\
\end{eqnarray}

see e.g. Buchen (2001) or Wilmott et al. (1995). Note that the option price is linked to the first passage time CDF through

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}^* \{ \nu > \tau \} & = & e^{r \tau} \tilde{V}(S, \tau)\\
& = & \int_\tau^\infty \mathbb{P}^* \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}\tau \}
\end{eqnarray}

and thus

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\mathrm{d} \tau} \mathbb{P}^* \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}\tau \} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \left\{ e^{r \tau} \tilde{V}(S, \tau) \right\}.
\end{equation}

Carefully differentiating the two terms in $\tilde{V}(S, \tau)$ yields

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} e^{r \tau} \mathcal{B}_B^\psi(S, \tau) & = & -\psi \mathcal{N}' \left( \psi d_-(S, B) \right) \frac{1}{2 \sigma \tau \sqrt{\tau}} \left( \ln \left( \frac{S}{B} \right) - \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \tau \right)
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} e^{r \tau} \mathcal{I} \left\{ \mathcal{B}_B^\psi(S, \tau) \right\} & = & -\psi \left( \frac{S}{B} \right)^{2 \alpha} \mathcal{N}' \left( \psi d_-(B, S) \right) \frac{1}{2 \sigma \tau \sqrt{\tau}} \left( \ln \left( \frac{B}{S} \right) - \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \tau \right).
\end{eqnarray}

Through some tedious algebra, we can show that

\begin{eqnarray}
\left( \frac{S}{B} \right)^{2 \alpha} \mathcal{N}' \left( \psi d_-(B, S) \right) & = & \mathcal{N}' \left( \psi d_-(S, B) \right)\\
& = & \mathcal{N}' \left( d_-(S, B) \right).
\end{eqnarray}

Consequently,

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\mathrm{d} \tau} \mathbb{P}^* \{ \nu \in \mathrm{d}\tau \} & = & \frac{-\psi \ln (B / S)}{\sigma \tau \sqrt{\tau}} \mathcal{N}' \left( d_-(S, B) \right).
\end{eqnarray}

It is easy to check that this is the same expression that we obtained before.

**References**

Buchen, Peter W. (2001) "Image Options and the Road to Barriers," *Risk Magazine*, Vol. 14, No. 9, pp. 127-130

Karatzas, Ioannis and Steven E. Shreve (1991) *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*: Springer, 2nd edition.

Musiela, Marek and Marek Rutkowski (2005): *Martingale Methods in Financial Modelling*: Springer.

Shreve, Steven E. (2004) *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II - Continuous Time Models*: Springer.

Wilmott, Paul, Sam Howison and Jeff Dewynne (1995) *The Mathematics of Financial Derivatives*: Cambridge University Press

Comment: +1, very nice explanation (I suspect there might be a slight notational problem with $\Bbb{P}^*$ and $\hat{\Bbb{P}}$ when you write abstract Bayes though - same when you give the distribution of the first passage time under $\hat{\Bbb{P}}$)

Comment: @Quantuple - thanks for pointing this out!